# Actionbar - hiding all menu items except search field

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I have a menu in my actionbar with two items. After opening search view "a piece of pen" is still displayed. How can I hide it?

menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit"
        android:title="@string/edit"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

</menu>
```

Actionbar:
[image: search closed]

Actionbar with search view opened:
[image: search open]

I tried also:

```
app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
```

But in this case I have:

[image: collapseActionView]

I want to get the same what is presented in the second picture. But edit icon should be hidden or eventually displayed but as a whole.

**EDIT**

Based @Ahmad Alsanie answer I wrote sth like this:

```
SearchView view = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
view.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) 
        menu.findItem(R.id.edit).setVisible(false);
});
```

And it works, but how can I restore edit icon after closing search view? I tried `setOnCloseListener` but unsuccessfully.

Comment: look at this link http://www.edumobile.org/android/action-bar-search-view/

Comment: Thx, I tried it, but it's the same what I have in the third picture (only programmatically, no xml)

Comment: Ok, nothing happened :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58470591/7972699 
this perfectly solve's this problem

Answer (score 8):

I did tried all the above solution's but none worked for me.The closest i got was with @ysfcyln [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45438613/7972699) but still not perfect.

So i will give my version of solution with step by step explanation

## Step 1:

crucial Issue's i faced:

- searchView was not covering the whole action bar
- actionUp button was not displayed

And once i declared `app:showAsAction= collapseActionView` it did all the magic, i.e covered the whole action bar and gave a back button.

> Note:Still other actionMenuItem's were visible. (Problem 2)

#### menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_note_add_24px"
        android:title="@string/add_note"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_setting"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icons_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_24px"
        android:title="@string/search_hint"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />

</menu>
```

## Step 2:

To Solve the Problem 2(Hide other menuItem's in overflow) i used [MenuItem. setOnActionExpandListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setOnActionExpandListener(android.view.MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener)).

The Code is from my project just to give idea, change according to you project's.

#### Activity/Fragment(below code is from a fragment):

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
...
...
   //get all menuItem using the id in onCreateOptionsMenu()
   val searchActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
   val settingActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_setting)
   val addActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_add)

   if (searchActionMenuItem is MenuItem) {
       searchActionMenuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(object :
       MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener {
       override fun onMenuItemActionExpand(p0: MenuItem?): Boolean {
          settingActionMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER)
          addActionMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER)
          return true
       }

      override fun onMenuItemActionCollapse(p0: MenuItem?): Boolean {
          activity?.invalidateOptionsMenu()
          return true
       }
      })
   }
...
...
}
```

Point's to be noted are:

- Use setOnActionExpandListener to check the change of SearchView state not the searchView's Listener as declared below.

  ```
  searchView.setOnSearchClickListener {  }  // Work's as expected
  searchView.setOnCloseListener {  }        // Doesn't get triggered as expected
  ```
- Set the ShowAsAction of other MenuItem's to `MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER` inside `onMenuItemActionExpand()` as it will force other item's to OverFlow Menu once SearchView is expanded.(Changing Visibility of MenuItem will not do the job)

  ```
   settingActionMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER)  
   addActionMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER)
  ```
- `onMenuItemActionCollapse()` call's activity's invalidateOptionsMenu().The reason is to reset the Action Menu bar Back to it's original state.

That's it from me, comment below if i missed any case.

#### ScreenShot's:

[image: SS1]

[image: SS2]

[image: SS3]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description!

Comment: I had to use setOnSearchClickListener and setOnCloseListener to get this to work. The setActionExpandListener was never called. Could be a due to different target SDK, I am using 30, or different Google library versions.

Answer (score 3):

First inside your `onCreateOptionsMenu` use this:

```
MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.edit, menu);
if (menu.getItem(1).isFocused()) //detect if search view has focus 
    {
        //hide only option 2 which is in this case edit pen
            menu.getItem(2).setVisible(false);
    }else{
    menu.getItem(2).setVisible(true);
    }
```

then use :

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();//to call onCreateOptionMenu again
```

Comment: Thx, where I should call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` ?

Comment: call invalidate for when you want the menu to be reupdated to display or hide edit . can be called any where in your class e.g onCreate

Comment: `menu.getItem(1)` doesn't have `isFocused` method. I tried to use `SearchView view` instead of this and it works but effect is still the same...

Comment: I tried to use `view.setOnFocusChangeListener` also but it still doesn't works :(

Comment: I think you will need to change `menu.getItem(2).isFocused()` to `menu.getItem(2).getActionView().isFocused()`

Answer (score 2):

@Ahmed Awad answer nice but searchView.setOnCloseListener not work so use MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener

**menu_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_sort"
        android:title="Sort"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_sort_alphabetically"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

**Activity**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_items, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

/*        // Hide other menu items when searchView clicked
        searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_sort).setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        // Show other menu items when SearchView closed
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_sort).setVisible(true);
                return false;
            }
        });*/

        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(menuItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                // Do something when collapsed
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_sort).setVisible(true);
                return true;  // Return true to collapse action view
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                // Do something when expanded
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_sort).setVisible(false);
                return true;  // Return true to expand action view
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: Improvised version of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58470591/7972699 as i faced many issue's in this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where I could not show the other icons correctly after hiding them. The below changes worked for me. You can give it a try.

1- Try to change the ShowAsAction to "always"

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit"
        android:title="@string/edit"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
```

2- Use the "setOnSearchClickListener" to hide the edit control as:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.edit).setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

3- Use the "setOnCloseListener" to restore the hidden control as:

```
// Detect SearchView close
searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        menu.findItem(R.id.edit).setVisible(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

You will not need to call invalidate for this to work

Comment: setOnSearchClickListener won't never triggered

Comment: @HaiHack https://stackoverflow.com/a/58470591/7972699 check this solution out

Answer (score -4):

Try to use for second menu app:showAsAction="never"